# Replace input file with my own button in the form

Tags: html, css

Basicly I want to hide the input file and use a button to choose a file in the form.
If I use `<label for="input-file">Label</label>` when I click the label i get to choose a file, but I would like to be a button or at least to look like a button.
Here is a [code sample in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yyhn7dL4/) :

```
input[type=file] { display: none; }

<form>
    <input type="file" id="input-file">
    <label for="input-file">
        <button>Button</button>
    </label>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

If I but a button in the label, it acts as a submit button, if I specify its type it does nothing on click.

Is there any way to have upload a file in the form using my button or a button looking control instead of using the `input type="file"`?
It must be a HTML-CSS solution, no JS or any framework.

**EDIT:**

This CSS code appears to make the `label` look like a standard button :

```css
label {
    appearance: button;
    -moz-appearance: button;
    -webkit-appearance: button;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 2px 6px 3px;
    border: 2px outset buttonface;
    font: 13.3333px Arial;
}
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You'll achieve this with couple of lines of CSS. [Fiddle](http://fiddly.org/64a16)

```css
input[type="file"] {
    display: none;
}
.custom-file-upload {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<label for="file-upload" class="custom-file-upload">
    <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i> Custom Upload
</label>
<input id="file-upload" type="file"/>
```

Comment: Nice, thanks. I will make the text to look like the default button.

Comment: Great. But I don't know why.

Comment: @Chao, the `<label ..>` atttribute **`for`** links the `input field` to itself with the **id** of the `<input type="file" id=... />`.  Notice the `id` of the `<input ...>` and `for` attribute of the `<label ...>` are same.

Comment: I'm curious how accessible is this?

Answer (score 6):

Your Html with simplte font awesome customization [FIddle](https://jsfiddle.net/asnastudio777/h7gau9wm/)

```css
.image-upload > input
{
    display: none;
}
.attach-doc
{
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="image-upload">
    <label for="file-input">
        <i class="attach-doc fa fa-paperclip fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </label>

    <input id="file-input" type="file"/>
</div>
```