# How to read and upload a file in reactjs using custom button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to upload and read a file locally, but I want to do that using a custom button not using HTML input.

```
<input type="file" id="my_file_input" />
```

I found this way but I don't want to use this shape or this button, I wanted to use a material UI Raised Button to do this functionality to match the other site Button.

I also tried the following way but it didn't work because as i clicked the button nothing happened.

```
<input type="file" id="my_file_input" style={{display:"none"}}/>
<label htmlFor="my_file_input">
    <RaisedButton
        label="Import from Excel"
        labelColor="#FFFFFF"
        backgroundColor="#01579b"
        />
</label>
```

I thought I should do the uploading/reading file functionality manually in the `onClick` function of the `RaisedButton` but I didn't find a way to do that.

So is there any other solution for this problem in react?

Comment: You can do this with HTML/CSS: [Replace input file with my own button in the form](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33553785/215552)

Comment: @HereticMonkey it works in html but doesn't work in react.

Comment: Sure it does. The solution does not depend on JavaScript, and React is JavaScript. If you really can't get it working, [edit] your question to include a [mcve], showing how you implemented it and how it "doesn't work". You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/338537/215552) to create a runnable snippet here on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 14):

I wanted to provide an update for using refs with functional components. Here is a quick example:

```js
Import React, {useRef} from 'React'

const myComponent = () => {
  const fileInputRef=useRef();
  
  const handleChange = (event) =>{
    // do something with event data

  }
  
  return(
    <>
      <button onClick={()=>fileInputRef.current.click()}>
        Custom File Input Button
      </button>
      <input onChange={handleChange} multiple={false} ref={fileInputRef} type='file'hidden/>
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: you have errors in your code

Answer (score 9):

I hope this code will help you.
We can solve it in two ways.

## 1-)

## HTML

```
<div>
<input type="file" hidden ref={this.inputReference} onChange={this.fileUploadInputChange} />
<button className="ui button" onClick={this.fileUploadAction}>
    Image Upload
</button>
{this.state.fileUploadState}
</div>
```

## REACT CONSTRUCTOR

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state={fileUploadState:""}
    this.inputReference = React.createRef();
}
```

## ONCLICK FUNCTION

```
fileUploadAction = () =>this.inputReference.current.click();
fileUploadInputChange = (e) =>this.setState({fileUploadState:e.target.value});
```

## 2-)

## HTML

```
<div>
<input id="fileButton" type="file" hidden />
<button onClick={this.fileUploadButton}>
    Image Upload
</button>
{this.state.fileUploadState}
</div>
```

## React State

```
this.state = {fileUploadState:""}
```

## React Function

```
fileUploadButton = () => {
document.getElementById('fileButton').click();
document.getElementById('fileButton').onchange = () =>{      
this.setState({
    fileUploadState:document.getElementById('fileButton').value
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

please read API of React Material https://material-ui.com/demos/buttons/

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

const styles = theme => ({
  button: {
    margin: theme.spacing.unit,
  },
  input: {
    display: 'none',
  },
});

function ContainedButtons(props) {
  const { classes } = props;
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        accept="image/*"
        className={classes.input}
        id="contained-button-file"
        multiple
        type="file"
      />
      <label htmlFor="contained-button-file">
        <Button variant="raised" component="span" className={classes.button}>
          Upload
        </Button>
      </label>
    </div>
  );
}

ContainedButtons.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(ContainedButtons);
```

Comment: I feel like there has to be a better way other than using a label as a button. I know sometimes it is hard to use semantic HTML in React depending on what you are trying to do, but it is good to try using semantic HTML where you can.

Answer (score 2):

As the doc says, you just need to add:

```
component="span"
```

To the button component.