# I get an error when dialing as a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, object

**My project(shortly):**

- I'm doing the bookmark section in the Yandex Browser.

---

**Problem:**

- I've made a bookmark before. The code on that project was:

```
$("#siteImg").change(function(e){
    for (var i = 0; i < e.originalEvent.srcElement.files.length; i++) {
        var file = e.originalEvent.srcElement.files[i];

        // image operation
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function() {
            source = String(reader.result);
        }
        console.log("asf")
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }
        addBookmark();
    })
```

There is no problem in this code. Working properly. But I do not want the program to work when the input changes in my current project. I want this code to work when a button is pressed. I wrote a code for this:

```
function imageData(e){
    for (var i = 0; i < e.originalEvent.srcElement.files.length; i++) {
        var file = e.originalEvent.srcElement.files[i];

        // image operation
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function() {
            source = String(reader.result);
        }
        console.log("asf")
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        addBookmark();
    }
}
```

This code is not working properly. Probably the cause of the problem "**e**". But I couldn't figure it out. The error message says:

[image]

[View the codes here](https://codepen.io/guldus/pen/pmogGY?editors=1100)

Comment: How are you calling `imageData()` ?

Comment: this can also happen, if the user clicks the input and cancel without choosing a file.

Comment: I installed the code at the end of the article (new). You better understand the problem from there. @Arshad

Comment: Is this an X/Y problem? If so, it's likely a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33553785/replace-input-file-with-my-own-button-in-the-form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`originalEvent` is part of `jQuery` and not `javascript`. In Javascript, you can access the `srcElement` from event directly.

```js
// jQuery
$('button').on('click', function(e) {
    console.log(e.originalEvent.srcElement);
});

// Javascript
const button = document.querySelector('button');
button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    console.log(e.srcElement);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sometimes occurs that when an inline event listener involves the event object, it won't be found. It's better to pass a function reference from your JavaScript:

```
$("#button").onclick = imageData;
```

Comment: But button does not have files

Comment: @mplungjan it's the submit button in the form.

Comment: I installed the code at the end of the article (new). You better understand the problem from there.

Comment: `e.originalEvent.srcElement` will not find `.files` on the submit event

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you are calling `imageData()` from different places. For Example :

```
$("#siteImg1").change(function(e){
     /**/
}

$("#siteImg2").change(function(e){
     /**/
}
```

You can handle it all image's change event at one place by adding a class `siteImg` and update your code like :

```
 $(".siteImg").change(function(e){
     imageData(e);
 }
```